# Complex valued smooth fuction and lateral limits

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f:(t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon)\backslash\{t_0\}\to\mathbb{C}^*$, $f\in C^{\infty}((t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon)\backslash\{t_0\})$ and $|f(t)|=1, \forall t\in (t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon)\backslash\{t_0\}$. We know that the following limit exists:

$\lim\limits_{t\to t_0} f^2(t)=z_0\in\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that the two sided limits of $f$ at $t_0$ exist? (i.e. $\exists\lim\limits_{t\nearrow t_0} f(t)$ and $\exists\lim\limits_{t\searrow t_0} f(t)$). Moreover they are either equal or opposite.